# Why does the loss function described in Faster R-CNN converge? Does my implementation match?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build an implementation of the RPN from Faster R-CNN for a project I am working on. I have been using some of code form [here](https://github.com/RockyXu66/Faster_RCNN_for_Open_Images_Dataset_Keras/blob/master/frcnn_train_vgg.ipynb) and trying to follow the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf). To limit the scope of this question, I will only be focused on the loss of the classification part of the RPN.

In the paper, they use log loss. In my implementation I am using binary crossentropy. This function minimized using a mini batch of the data of size 256 attempting to balance positive and negatives.

[image: Loss]

During training, I noticed the loss decreasing very rapidly. I investigated and realized it was quickly learning to guess the corners of images. The corners of images are never included in mini-batches. Thus, by maximizing the probability of the corners, it kind of circumvents the loss function. Upon reading further, I realized that I do not understand why this loss function works.

I have built the neural network and a series of functions that map a `(224, 224, 3)` image to a `(14, 14, 9, 2)` (Note: `image_height / stride = 14`, `anchor_sizes * anchor_shapes = 9`). The pairs of points in the last dimension correspond to validity (is it part of my sample?) and parity (positive or negative anchor), respectively.

My loss function is as follows:

```
loss = lambda_rpn_class * K.sum(y_true[...,0] * 
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true[...,1], y_pred[:,:,:,:,0]))
                            / K.sum(epsilon + y_true[...,0])
```

Where `y_true.shape = (?, 14, 14, 9, 2)` and `y_pred.shape = (?, 14, 14, 9, 1)`. I am trying to simulate the mini batch by switching the loss off for non valid samples.

Can you help me understand why the loss function in the paper works theoretically? Is there an issue in the logic of my approach matching the paper or can I assume that there is something else going on?

Comment: I don't understand, you say that you will only concentrate on the classification loss of the RPN, but then you talk about guessing corners (that is the bounding box regression loss), so what is the actual issue? That the loss decreases fast?

Comment: Both $L_{cls}$ and $L_{box}$ are normal loss functions from classification (logloss) and regression (smooth L1), which are proved to be able to converge.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is a classification. It predicts the the class of corners to be positives.

Comment: @YilunZhang I understand mathematically that it has a minimum. I want to understand why this works when you have an 'on/off' switch for mini batch.